# bearing frequency detection

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency, cepstral-analysis

I am working on bearing faults detection. I am doing the following steps:
signal->mean zero->high pass->hilbert->y->fft->cepstrum of y.
[image: this is my spectrum after hilbert and fft]

[image: this is the cepstrum]

my code is:

```
    analy = hilbert(Signal);
    y = abs(analy);
    N = 2*2048;T=N/Fs;
    sig_f = abs(fft(y(1:N)',N));
    sig_n = sig_f/(norm(sig_f));
    Signal_fft_hilbert = sig_n;
    freq_s = (0:N-1)/T;    

       figure(3)
      plot(freq_s(2:250),Signal_fft_hilbert(2:250))
      title ('Average FFT after Hilbert enveloping');
     xlabel('Frequency in Hz')

      figure(4)
      c2=cceps(y(2:250));
     plot(freq_s(2:250),c2)
```

The problem is I am not able to extract the fundamental frequency out of the spectrum or cepstrum. my bearing frequency is 42 Hz.I am not getting prominent peaks in this region. Please suggest something.

Comment: The spectrum appears to have a fundamental frequency and third and fifth harmonics -- all of which are below 200Hz. Are you sure the *bearing* frequency is 42Hz? There are other frequencies related to it (http://electromotores.com/PDF/InfoT%C3%A9cnica/EASA/Understanding%20Bearing%20Vibration%20Frequencies.pdf: FTF, BSF, BPFO, BPFI that may be relevant).

Comment: well yes the bearing frequency is 42 Hz.and I am taking the cepstrum after fft. Is that correct? Or i need to take it after hilbert transform?

Comment: Oh I get your doubt. It is the fundamental ball frequency.